# React JS error - Expecting "CALC", ,..........."dimension", "number", got unexpected end of input CompileError: Begins at CSS selector undefined

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

I build my whole project, but when I'm doing yarn build, I'm getting this error from yarn i.e.

```
Parse error on line 1: 
^
Expecting "CALC", "LPAREN", "ADD", "SUB", "FUNCTION", "LENGTH", "ANGLE", "TIME", "FREQ", "RES", "UNKNOWN_DIMENSION", "EMS", "EXS", "CHS", "REMS", "VHS", "VWS", "VMINS", "VMAXS", "PERCENTAGE", "NUMBER", "expression", "math_expression", "function", "dimension", "number", got unexpected end of input
CompileError: Begins at CSS selector undefined


error Command failed with exit code 1
```

And I don't really think I did something wrong.. I tried creating a new react-app but and put all the files there, but still the same error:(

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and got it fixed. This is caused by some typo in a .css file. For me, I had "text-align: calc();" in the /src/App.css file that creating a new react-app makes. I suspect you have a similar issue of using a css function without including an expression.